# IdentityServer role/permissions in AngularJS and WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I have and AngularJS application that talks to WebAPI. Both login using Identity Server 3. I have an Admin role, but I want to expand on this so I can hide certain admin functionality in the front end from some admin users. So I need to check user permissions for admin users. What's the best way to do this? Do I just create a table in my database and assign permssions to users there? Or is there something in identity server I should do to assign permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that application permissions would be tracked in your application specific database. In that database, you *could* track permissions by role (rather than user). Then, you could use the role claim(s) that come back in the token to look up the proper permissions. However, that's just one method...

This is a really great post on the subject written by Dominick Baier, one of the authors of Identity Server: [Identity vs. Permissions](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/)